# Help identify this resistor

Tags: resistors, identification, component-values

I'm a little stumped by this one. I'm currently repairing an old control board, and replacing the majority of the components.

I've come across this resistor (pictured below). Reading the color band  it should be a 22 kΩ, 5% resistor (red, red, orange, gold). Measuring out of circuit with a multimeter reads 120 kΩ. Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Resistor Pulled out of Circuit]

Comment: The simplest explanation is usually the right one.   You have a bad resistor there, it's marked 22k but it's failed.   Looks like that might be an old carbon composition.  When they fail, they can crack internally and the resistance goes up as a result.

Comment: @Kyle B if you put that up as an answer I would upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KyleB has stated, the resistor may be damaged internally.

Carbon-resistors are kind of "replace on first sight in faulty assemblys" components.

I would tend to go with the color marking or the documented value (schematic if avialable, or PCB markings in silkscreen).

**My advice:**

Go with 22k-1% and make sure to get the "wattage" correct.

Comment: Modern day carbon resistors ARE NOT "replace on first sight". You can get fantastic surge performance out of them: https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-1625876-8.datasheet.pdf

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for the comment. Do carbon resistors have superior surge performance (peak voltage and surge current i guess) over metall resistors in general? Or is this a specific - by now, according  to the datasheet, obsolete - series? If so: on what property is this performance based? Are they capeable of "more joules/per mass*kelvin"?

Comment: Thanks @ElectronicsStudent for the answer, I'll accept it. Some very informative information from Andy aka also. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Carbon Comp are hygroscopic - Meaning they absorb water.  This makes them drift in value over time.   I do alot of maintenance/repair on vintage vacuum tube amplifiers - They're chock full of carbon comps!   Sometimes I'll replace them with modern metal film equivalents as carbon comp can be very noisy, but other times it's appropriate to replace with new CC.   CC have an odd characteristic --- their resistance changes slightly as the voltage across them changes.  This adds a touch of "compression" to the audio - It's a part of the "warmth" of vintage tube amps.

Comment: So resistors in the power rails - Those get replaced with metal film. Superior lifetimes, less noise.  Plate load resistors are part of the signal path however, so those are always replaced with new CC.   Cathode resistors - Purists use CC there but the developed voltage is so low (a volt or so) it hardly could help the compression effect so I use metal film there.  Etc... season to taste...

Comment: @KyleB Wow - did not know about this property! Thank you! Do you happen to know how "steep" the change is? Like: Are we talking dR of 1% over 1000V applied or dR of 10% over 10V (Extremes, i know). And another question: Do the non-linear effects lead to distortion? Is this distortion felt as "warmth"? Or what is "warmth" based on?

Comment: That's a question that can't be answered in these comments  ;)   Yes, it's "distortion".  But the good kind of distortion  ;)     If you're curious, this is a very readable treatise on vacuum tube preamps.  If you've previously studied load lines for transistor amplifiers, you'll have no problem zipping through this. 
   https://www.valvewizard.co.uk/gainstage.html    Audio tube amps typically operate around maybe 200-500V DC to give you an idea of the voltages across the resistors.

Comment: @KyleB Thank you for the link. I will have a read! A first "look" seems interesting! Another question: (Please forgive me if it sounds rude) Is "warmth" some kind of "i hear it", or can one measure it? I mean: How to distinguishe between good/bad distortion? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: The distortion in a vacuum tube amp is very different from a transistor amp.  When a signal hits a power rail in a transistor amp, you get a sudden and hard cutoff.   This causes a 'buzz saw' kind of distortion (metal guitarist love this...)   But in a vacuum tube amp, that doesn't happen -- The signal gets "squished".   You get a softer distortion.  It sounds good because the resulting harmonics largely end up being musically related to the fundamental note - It thickens up the sound.   (It's also very subjective!)  https://milbert.com/articles/tubes_vs_transistors_perception

Comment: @KyleB Okay, thank you! This makes sense! The article is realy interesting!